# text values to be entered in jsp for registration form

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am doing one small requirement on servlet and jsp.

servlet will contain variables id,name,email,gender. some times the values will be null.

Some times the values of the varaible are null. For example id and name are containing the values 1123 and pratap.

```
response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
              try {
             //TODO output your page here
        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("registration.jsp");
    view.forward(request, response);
           request.setAttribute("id","value"); 
        } finally {            

        }
```

my jsp page

```
 <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title>JSP Page</title>
        </head>
        <body>
          <form method="GET" action='registration1'>
    <input type="text" name="address"/>
    <input type="text" name="phoneno"/>

    <input type="text" name="pincode" />
    <label>${id}</label>
    <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

so that the control is going to registration.jsp

In registration.jsp i should get the text boxes for email and gender and for the id and name i should get the values in the text boxes such that the user can not change those values.(because those are already filled and proved to be correct.)

for the above jsp i tried with id but i am unable to see the id value in jsp.

how to pass those varaibles to the text boxes of the jsp and making the prompt to enter the values if the value is null.

Thank you..

Comment: first of all rectify mistakes in your question(3rd and 4th paragraph)

Comment: What you want? text box can not be edit or it can...

Comment: @SachinJ if the value is null the text box should be edit..if it is not null then it should not be edit......first of all i am unable to get the value in the jsp page(the id value)

Comment: @HardikMishra my jsp page is shown..

Comment: I have added an example.Add more controls as per your need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need set values as request  attributes in Servlet and get them in JSP.
After getting them in JSP, Check accordingly and enable /disable the form controls.

Servlet:

`request.setAttribute("phoneno","9998386033");`

JSP:

```
<%
String phoneno=null;
if(request.getAttribute("phoneno")!=null) 
    phoneno = request.getAttribute("phoneno").toString();
%>

<% if(phoneno!=null) {
     out.println("<INPUT TYPE=\"text\" name=\"phoneno\" value=\""+phoneno+"\" disabled=\"disabled\" ");
   } else {
       out.println("<INPUT TYPE=\"text\" name=\"phoneno\" ");
   }
%>
```

FOR JSP EL

```
<c:if test="${empty phoneno}">
    <INPUT TYPE="text" name="phoneno" value="${phoneno}" disabled="disabled"/>
</c:if>
<c:if test="${not empty phoneno}">
    <INPUT TYPE="text" name="phoneno"/>
</c:if>
```

Comment: i have got the answer..but it is with the code that you have given at first...In the present jsp you mentioned ${name} what is that it is refering to .......(in my code instead of phoneno i used the id1...here is the code.. <%
String id1=null;
if(request.getAttribute("id")!=null) 
    id1 = request.getAttribute("id").toString();
%>

<% if(id1!=null) {
     out.println("<INPUT TYPE=\"text\" name=\"id1\" value=\""+id1+"\" disabled=\"disabled\" ");
   } else {
       out.println("<INPUT TYPE=\"text\" name=\"id1\" ");
   }
%>

Comment: i will put it as accepted answer..just want to know the meaning of ${name}...when i put ${id1} it is not working...

Comment: 'name` was typo in example 1. I edited example in hurry. :(. `name` could be any valid attribute name which you need to set in Servlet.